# How to make this python script faster?

Tags: python

I tried to find an overlap list from two set of list.
I first generate first list by

```
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    list_1.append(line)
```

and use this list to scanning through the second file:

```
while True:
    line1=f1.readline()
    if not line1:
        break
    for i in list_1:
        if i==line1[:17]:
            list_2.append(line1)
```

Comment: Is line order important for you?

Comment: What should happen if empty line occurs in the middle of file? Is it ok that the half of file will be ignored?

Comment: There is no "empty line" taht will match "if not line" in the midle of a file - readline leaves the "\n" charater on the string, and this will evaluate to 
True.

Answer (score 4):

ThiefMasters answer will output the common lines in arbitrary order. If you want the items output in the same order as they appear in one of the files, first read the *other* file into a set:

```
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    file1_set = set(f)
```

Then search through the file that controls the order:

```
with open("file2.txt") as f:
    list2 = [line for line in f if line in file1_set]
```

If the generated `list2` does not fit in memory (I guess this is rather far fetched) we can still make it work by writing the results back to an output file continuously:

```
with open("file2.txt") as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as out:
        for line in f:
            if line in file1_set:
                out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as none of the files is excessively big, store all lines in [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) and then compare those sets:

```
lines_1 = set(f)
lines_2 = set(f1)
lines_in_both = lines_1 & lines_2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the differences in two files you can also use the difflib module, which is included in the python standard library.  The module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It can be used for example, for comparing files, and can produce difference information in various formats, including HTML and context and unified diffs. You can find useful comparison methods in the [difflib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher).

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, file1.read(), file2.read())
```